# PredicateBuilder, VB.net and Where()

Tags: vb.net, where-clause, predicatebuilder

I am building a predicate in VB.net using the PredicateBuilder class from the LinqKit library.
My datasource is a manually constructed datatable.
All the examples I've found show folks creating the predicate and then passing that predicate as an argument to the `Where()` method on the datatable.AsEnumerable().

But intellisense is telling me that the `Where()` method takes a paremeter of type "`System.Func`", but the type returned by PredicateBuilder is "`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))`"

What am I missing?

Example:

```
        Dim ds As DataTable = getData()

        Dim tmp As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = New DataTable().AsEnumerable()

        ' CREATE DYNAMIC LINQ WHERE CLAUSE
        Dim predicate As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of DataRow, Boolean)) = PredicateBuilder.True(Of DataRow)()

        If cbHPMS_ShowRequired.Checked Then
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("RECORD_TYPE") = "REQUIRED")
        End If
        If cbHPMS_ShowOptional.Checked Then
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("RECORD_TYPE") = "OPTIONAL")
        End If
        If cbHPMS_EmptyRecord.Checked Then
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("RECORD_STATUS") = "EMPTY")
        End If
        If cbHPMS_PartialRecord.Checked Then
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("RECORD_STATUS") = "PARTIAL")
        End If
        If cbHPMS_CompletedRecord.Checked Then
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("RECORD_STATUS") = "COMPLETE")
        End If
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ddHPMS_RoadName.SelectedValue) And Not ddHPMS_RoadName.SelectedValue.Equals("Select") Then
            predicate = predicate.And(Function(x As DataRow) x("RoadName") = ddHPMS_RoadName.SelectedValue)
        End If

        tmp = ds.AsEnumerable().Where(predicate)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not used LinqKit but  would think it would be like

```
tmp = ds.AsEnumerable().Where(predicate.Compile())
```

Comment: Excellent!  Solved my problem immediately.  Thanks!